Simulating Microcontroller-Microcomputer Communication in Webots
How can I simulate communication between a microcontroller and a microcomputer on a robot in Webots without using ROS? Specifically, I want the microcontroller to read sensor values using C code, while the microcomputer is responsible for navigation. What would be the best approach to set up this simulation?
